# My question is about nfs server configuration commands in fedora, Where it should be asked?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I already know it is not totally about programming, but I need to know how I can configure my nfs-server in Fedora using linux commands.

I think I should ask this question at Ask Ubuntu, but I am not sure because I want my commands for fedora.

Or is it good to ask this question on Stack Overflow by tagging [fedora](/questions/tagged/fedora) and [nfs](/questions/tagged/nfs)? Or should I go to make a new account on Server Fault, I'm afraid because I think my question will be declared as off topic, or it will be downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

If your question is not programming related, then **definitely** don't ask it on Stack Overflow.

Also, since your question is not about Ubuntu, you probably shouldn't ask on an Ubuntu-specific site.

You may be interested in the [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) site. Acceptable questions, per their [FAQ](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq):

> - Using or administering a *nix desktop or server
> - The Unix foundation underlying MacOS (but generally not frontend application questions)
> - The underlying *nix OS on an embedded system or handheld device (e.g. an Android phone)
> - Shell scripting
> - Applications packaged in *nix distributions (*note: [being cross-platform does not disqualify](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/97/29)*)
> - UNIX C API and System Interfaces ( *[within reason](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/314/29)* )

Related tags: [[fedora]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fedora) [[nfs]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs)

Comment: Is this a beta site

Comment: No, it is a graduated site.

Comment: Oh.., Thanks for refering me to such a good website.